# How to fill entire browser window on initial load

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How would I fill the entire browser window with the dark brown color.  Right now, the top of a YouTube video is clipping the bottom.  To better understand what it is I'm describing, I'll attach at picture.[image]

On the initial page load, I do not want to see the top of YouTube video, but just the brown background.

Comment: You should post relevant HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<div class="mask"></div>

.mask {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 11;
  background-color: brown;
}
```